# How to turn off the device option in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

My Chrome browser automatically got updated and now it displays a weird device bar on top as shown in the screenshot below:

Any ideas how to remove the bar?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open Settings (via the triple horizontal bar icon on the very right of the address bar).

Then open 'More Tools' and then 'Developer Tools'

In the tool bar of the developer panel there will be a blue highlighted smartphone icon. Click that to get rid of the device ruler.

[image: blue smartphone icon]

Comment: That resets the mobile emulator. I don't want to do that. I still want to run the mobile emulator I just don't want to see the stupid scale toolbar at the top.

Comment: The blue mobile button exits the mobile emulator. I do NOT want to exit the emulator I just want to hide that stupid ruler.